What font is this Win11 system clock? (it's not Segoe UI/Variable)

In Windows 11 24H2, this is my taskbar system clock. Everywhere I've looked online says that the default font for Windows 11, including for the clock time, is Segoe UI or Segoe UI Variable. HOWEVER, in those fonts the character 1 does not have a crossbar at the bottom, whereas in my screenshot you can see that it does.
I have even tried examining the Windows style configuration using msstyleEditor but I can only find references to Segoe UI. Can anyone help ID this font? (I am trying to make myself a taskbar utility that matches the clock stylistically.)

Interesting... on Win 10, there's no bar on 1. Perhaps it's a holdover of MS Calibri, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/calibri, which is sans serif, but does have one on the one. Search for text with Calibri, UTF8 or Unicode.
